# How do I modify the content of a Copied Component when it is being copied?

Tags: event-system

In my code I am invoking the CopyEvent while copying a component from one location to another. While copying I need to modify the content in the Destination Component.

I tried using the `CopyEventArgs.CopiedObject` which is allowing me to get the details of the copied object but is not allowing me to set or modify any of the details of the object.

How can I modify the component I am copying when the destination component is created?

Comment: Karthik, welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange Site and thanks for this great question! I have updated your question slightly to provide additional clarification on what you are asking. If you disagree with my edits, please feel free to revert my changes.

Answer (score 5):

At a guess (without testing) I think you need to:

1. Copy the component
2. Check out the copied component
3. Make your changes
4. Save and CheckIn your component

Since you're using an event, I assume you're using TOM.NET. You should get your functionality with something along these lines (untested code):

```cs
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(Component.Content, Component.Schema);
XhtmlField myField = (XhtmlField)fields["MyField"];
myField.Value = "new value";
Component.CheckOut();    
Component.Content = fields.ToXml();
Component.Save(true);
if(Component.IsCheckedOut)
    Component.CheckIn();
```